# Calculate an equation with input in textfield - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I'm working on a app in Xcode and have run into a problem.
My app needs to collect input from a TextField (where the user enters information) an put it into my equation & eventually give the user a result.

For example - a
user enters their Weight, Height and Age.

My app then needs to take these inputs and place them into the following equation:

```
Men: RMR = 66,473 + (13,751*WEIGHT) + (5,0033*HEIGHT) - (6,755*AGE)
```

But how do I code this? What I have made so far:

My .h file is as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IBOutlet UITextField *Weight;
IBOutlet UITextField *Height;
IBOutlet UITextField *Age;

IBOutlet UILabel *rectResult;


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Weight;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Height;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Age;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rectResult;

-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender;


@end
```

and my .m file:

```
@implementation ViewController



-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
    float floatRectResult=[Weight.text floatValue]*
    [Age.text floatValue];
    NSString *stringRectResult=[[NSString alloc]
                                initWithFormat:@"%1.2f",floatRectResult];

    rectResult.text=stringRectResult;


}





- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

PS.: Sorry for my English - Can anybody help me? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {

    //66,473 + (13,751*WEIGHT) + (5,0033*HEIGHT) - (6,755*AGE)
    float result = (66473 + (13751*[Weight.text floatValue]) + (50033*[Height.text floatValue]) - (6755*[Age.text floatValue]));

    rectResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", result];
}
```

Since you appear to be using some constants, it may be better to `#define` them so that you can easily change them later. Example:

```
//Above your implementation
#define kWeightConst 13751.0 //Can be used later as just kWeightConst
```